# Working with cookies and session inside PHP class

Tags: php, oop, session, cookies

I have some function (pasted below little piece of function), which I used as separate function and it worked well.

Now I want to move this functon into some class. As you see, it works with `$_SESSION` and `$_COOKIE`.

Question is, is it required to send `$_SESSION` and `$_COOKIE` as input data while calling this function (I mean something like that: calling like `protect($_SESSION, $_COOKIE)` and then fetch them from inside function)? or it will work without sending them?

```
...
public function protect() {
    session_start();

    if (isset($_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
        if ($_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] != md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
            $this->logout();
            exit;
        }
    }

    if (!isset($_SESSION['id']) && !isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
        if (isset($_COOKIE['id']) && isset($_COOKIE['key'])) {

 ...
```

Comment: Is this class/function all about logins and user authorization? (If so, dealing with PHPs session and cookie interfaces seems okay.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_COOKIE` and `$_SESSION` are [superglobals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php), which means they are available everywhere. You never need to import them, pass them as arguments or anything similar, they are always available in any scope.

For this reason, they should **always** be treated as read-only - assigning a new value to them will affect the rest of the scripts execution in every scope.

Answer (score 2):

`$_SESSION` AND `$_COOKIE` are superglobals, meaning they are available in all scopes.  So it is not strictly necessary to pass them as parameters to functions.

However, there is a benefit in passing them as parameters when you start unit testing. Parameters will make it considerably easier to test values to the function without needing them to be available in `$_SESSION` or `$_COOKIE`.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to pass the `$_SESSION` or `$_COOKIE` variables as they are superglobals - accessible from anywhere ... [from the docs](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) :

> This is a 'superglobal', or automatic global, variable. This simply means that it is available in all scopes throughout a script. There is no need to do global $variable; to access it within functions or methods.